# Get checkbox values on checked and not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bind

I have some checkboxed that I need to get values, and calculate in new elements, but I need that to calculate when is checked and when is not checked.

```
<div id="dodaci">

<input name="checkboxes1" id="checkboxes-1" value="100" type="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes2" id="checkboxes-2" value="150" type="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes3" id="checkboxes-3" value="150" type="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes4" id="checkboxes-4" value="120" type="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes5" id="checkboxes-5" value="70" type="checkbox">
</div>

<div id="cena1">750<div>
```

I need to add values of checked boxes to value in cena1, and i need to get when is not checked to get minus?

Here is jQuery I have so far

```
$(function() { 
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    $('#dodaci :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    $('#cena1').append(', '+ $(this).val()); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Checkboxes should have unique names and **need** unique IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like the below code :

```
$(function() { 
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
     var cenaNum = parseInt($('#cena1').text());
    if(this.checked){
         $('#cena1').text(value+cenaNum);          
    }
    else {
        $('#cena1').text(cenaNum-value);
    }    
});
});
```

Here is the working link of fiddle :

[**Demo :  Jsfiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/srahel007/GzB7r/)

Comment: Sorry all ok, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#id:checked')`; 
 which returns `true` or `false`, so don't bind it to the `each()` method
and by id I mean an unique `ID` like `<input name="checkboxes1" id="checkboxes-1">`

**EDIT**

Change:

```
$('#cena1').append(', '+ $(this).val());
```

To something like: (**Didn't test!!**)

```
if ($('#id:checked')) {
    $('#cena1')
        .append(
            parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 
            parseInt($('#id:checked').val(), 10)
    );
} else {
    $('#cena1')
        .append(
            parseInt($(this).text(), 10) - 
            parseInt($('#id').not(':checked').val(), 10)
    );
}
```

**EDIT II**

This has nothing to do with your question directly, but it's better to name `inputs` the same as its `ID`

So NOT:

```
<input name="checkboxes1" id="checkboxes-1">
```

But:

```
<input name="checkboxes-1" id="checkboxes-1">
```

Comment: Ok, how on click to calculate values and on other click to get minus?

Comment: Fixed txanks, but prevous solution is better :

Comment: It's true, myne is like quick and dirty ;-)